# Need help to write a compare function

Tags: python

need help to write the compare part of this program as a function

```
import random
import sys

def myScript():

    ett = random.randint (1, 100)
    tva = random.randint (1, 100)

    print ("tal1", ett, "\n""tal2", tva)

    if (ett > tva):
        print ("tal1 är störst")
    elif (tva > ett):
        print ("tal2 är störst")
    else:
        print("talen är lika stora")       

    print ("vill du testa igen y/n")
    yes = set(['y'])
    no = set(['n'])

    choice = input().lower()
    if choice in yes:
        myScript()
    elif choice in no:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'y' or 'n'")
    myScript()

myScript()
```

Comment: You do realize this is not a very good question? Explain, elaborate, what exactly do you need to do, what have you tried etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which of the comparisons do you want to break out into a separate function?

Comment: < if (ett > tva):
        print ("tal1 är störst")

    elif (tva > ett):
        print ("tal2 är störst")

    else:
        print("talen är lika stora")
>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `compare part` as a function.

```
def my_compare(n, m):
   if cmp(n, m) == 1:
       return "tal1 är störst"
   elif cmp(n, m) == -1:
       return "tal2 är störst"
   else:
       return "talen är lika stora"
```

Now use this in your program like

```
print(my_compare(ett, tva))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I just broke the compare into a separate function and stopped the recursion from building up the call stack.

```
import random
import sys

def mycompare(ett, tva):
    if (ett > tva):
        print ("tal1 är störst")
    elif (tva > ett):
        print ("tal2 är störst")
    else:
        print("talen är lika stora")

def myScript():

    ett = random.randint (1, 100)
    tva = random.randint (1, 100)

    print ("tal1", ett, "\n""tal2", tva)
    mycompare(ett, tva)

    print ("vill du testa igen y/n")
    yes = 'y'
    no = 'n'

    while True:
        choice = input().lower()
        if choice == yes:
            return True
        elif choice == no:
            return False
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'y' or 'n'")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while myScript():
        pass
```